# Select a sub List<T> with filtering condition List<int> using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am struggling with producing a sublist of objects with Linq.

```
var assignedObject = new List<int>();
foreach (var obj in myObjects) {
    if (IsAssigned(obj)) {
        assignedObject.add(obj.Id);
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is remove assigned objects from `myObjects` with Linq `.Where(Func<T,bool> predicate)`.

```
myObjects = myObject.Where(item => item.Id != assignedObj.All()).ToList();
```

`item.Id != assignedObj.All()` is the problem part.

**If it is achievable with Linq please educate me.**

Otherwise, I am going to implement a loop.

```
var remainingObjects = new List<MyClass>();
foreach(var obj in myObjects) {
    if (!(assignedObjects.IndexOf(obj.Id) > -1)) {
        remainingObjects.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

PS: In case you're wondering `List<MyClass> myObjects = GetMyObjects(params);` which retrieved from somewhere else.

Comment: Are you just looking for `item => assignedObj.Contains(item.id)`? It's not very clear at the moment. If you could post a [mcve] it would make it easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet Now why didn't I think of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var toRemove = myObjects.Where(item=>assignedObj.Any(a=>a.Id == item.Id)).ToArray()
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your `All()` with a condition, like this:

```
myObjects = myObject
    .Where(item => assignedObj.All(assigned => item.Id !=  assigned.Id))
    .ToList();
```

However, it is easier to use `Contains`:

```
var assignedIds = new HashSet<int>(assignedObject);
myObjects = myObject.Where(item => assignedIds.Contains(item.Id)).ToList();
```

Using `HashSet<int>` speeds up the lookup in situations when `assignedObject` is relatively large - say, hundreds of objects or more.

Answer (score 1):

It can be like this: `var list = from item in myObjects where IsAssigned(item) select item`

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`var assignedObjects = myObjects.Where(m => IsAssigned(m)).ToList()`
`var remainedObjects = myObjects.Where(m => !IsAssigned(m)).ToList()`